# Angular and Jasmine test case - Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I am building an Ionic 4 + Angular 7 App. In the app I have a video page in which I am getting video URLs from a backend API via injectable services. The call from the page to videoService is handled in an async function **fetchVideoData()**

```
async fetchVideoData() {
    await this.videoService.getVideos().subscribe(data => {
        this.videoData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        const videoDataArrayLength = this.videoData.videosURLs.length;
        const videoArray = [];
        const videoUrlsArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < videoDataArrayLength; i++) {
            videoArray.push(this.videoData.videosURLs[i]);
            videoUrlsArray.push(this.videoData.videosURLs[i]['videoUrl']);
            if (this.videoData.videosURLs[i]['id'] === this.videoIdFromGameDetailPage) {
                this.arrayIterator = Number(this.videoData.videosURLs[i]['id']);
                this.arrayIterator--;
                this.videoUrlFetched = this.videoData.videosURLs[this.arrayIterator]['videoUrl'];
            }
        }
        this.isUrlYoutube = this.videoUrlFetched.includes(this.substring);
    });
}
```

this function is being called in **ngOnInit()**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(data => {
        this.videoIdFromGameDetailPage = data['vid'];
    });
    this.fetchVideoData().then(() => {
        this.isDataFromVideoApiReady = true;
    });
}
```

All this is working fine. The issue is in test case of this **fetchVideoData()** async method

Here is the test case for this method -

```
it('should get video data from observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    let arrayIteratorStub: number;
    let videoUrlFetchedStub: string;
    spy = spyOn(videoService, 'getVideos').and.returnValue(of(videoDataStub));
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    component.fetchVideoData().then((result) => {
        expect(videoService.getVideos).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.videoData).toBe(videoDataStub);
        for (let i = 0; i < videoDataStub.videosURLs.length; i++) {
            expect(videoDataStub.videosURLs[i]['id']).toEqual(ActivatedRouteSpy.params['vid']);
            arrayIteratorStub = Number(videoDataStub.videosURLs[i]['id']);
            arrayIteratorStub--;
            videoUrlFetchedStub = videoDataStub.videosURLs[arrayIteratorStub]['videoUrl'];
        }
        isUrlYouTubeStub = videoUrlFetchedStub.includes('youtube');
        expect(component.isUrlYoutube).toEqual(isUrlYouTubeStub);
    });
}));
```

While running the test case I am getting this -
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined**

And I am stuck at this. I have no idea why it's returning that error. I have tried everything that I know of. Can anyone help me with this? I am new to Angular and Ionic so many times I don't know what am I doing?

Comment: You're using await, but on a function call which doesn't return a promise. How could it possibly work?

Comment: also, why are you not using `.map` over observable rather than using `async` and all. Its not  a good practice

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ya I don't know much about best practices. I was just making things work on any basis. I scraped the whole file. Thanks.